# Where is LPPICTURE defined?

Tags: c++, windows

I'm trying to write a function to load a JPEG, and I've downloaded the sample code from MSDN Q218972, but it is using precompiled headers and I am not.

I've spent **hours** looking for where `LPPICTURE` and `OleLoadPicture()` are defined but can't find it anywhere.

1. Does anyone know which header I need to include for these two?
2. In future, is there any resource I can use to find this information? MSDN documents the .NET world extremely well and it's often trivial to find what I need to include, but I'm finding that it takes *longer* to identify headers to include for my Win32 program than to learn how to write a Win32 program!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`OleLoadPicture()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693724%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is defined in `OleCtl.h` and implemented in `OleAut32.dll`. The import library is `OleAut32.lib`.

The information is found towards the bottom of the [MSDN topic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693724%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

As for `LPPICTURE`, that is also defined when you include `OleCtl.h`.

Comment: Thanks. Are you talking about http://support.microsoft.com/kb/218972 ?? There is no reference to `OleCtl.h` or `OleAut32.dll` there.

Comment: No, I'm talking about the link to the documentation for [`OleLoadPicture()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693724%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in my answer.

Comment: Oh, there it is. Right near the bottom!